# Return Fetched Data from Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Have a question about rendering fetched data with Axios. I’m able to log returned data to the console, however, it will not render on the screen.

I’m using an NPM Bitly module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitly

```
const BitlyClient = require('bitly');
const bitly = BitlyClient('ACCESS TOKEN');
```

**State**

```
  class Example extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 
        landing: 'https://www.google.com/',
        newUrl: 'https://www.udacity.com/'
};
```

**API Call**

```
 componentDidMount() {
      bitly.shorten(this.state.landing)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({newUrl: response.data.url })
        console.log(response.data.url);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
```

This returns data to the console but does not render to the page.

**Render to Page**

```
<Component> {this.newUrl} </>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `{this.state.newUrl}`.

Comment: Thank you. I Included the sate as soon as I posted the question right before you responded and it worked. 

Need to learn not to jump the gun haha. 

Thank you for contributing, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Literally started to work as soon as I posted this smh.

I just updated the component to include the state.

Did not work

```
<Component> {this.newUrl} </>
```

Does Work

```
<Component> {this.state.newUrl} </>
```